# Does anybody have CATIA programming user manual for VB?

Tags: vb.net, catia

I need to develop CATIA addin using Visual Basic. Does anyone have CATIA programming help or user manual?

Comment: Pretty sure Dassault has one.  Always ask the vendor first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you are aiming for a macro, but from personal experience I can recommend looking into a possibility of building a standalone app which uses CATIA's API. The reason for that is because you can use Visual Studio (even express version) to develop the app with functionality you need with way more possibilities. At work I started with macro's with some interface and so on, but very soon got stuck facing the limitations of it. Switched to a standalone app - and till today I keep on adding amazing (for our needs) functionality with such an ease. So not a direct answer, but a frie

Answer (score 4):

If you're aiming to develop a macro in VBA (Visual Basic for Application) the documentation is  available in chm format in your CATIA installation:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dassault Systemes\B19\intel_a\code\bin\V5Automation.chm
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search for CATIA Portable Script Center also on Internet.

[Direct link](http://files.engineering.com/getfile.aspx?folder=5c7a05dd-7ecc-4888-9a54-4f5f63f8b501&file=CATIA_Portable_Script_Center_v2.0.zip)

Regards
Fernando

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer doesn't give much value. Maybe you at least could provide a direct link to the resource?

Comment: Hi, You are right, I thought searching with Google you could find a lot of references...then I found many of them are not so clear :-). A direct link is http://files.engineering.com/getfile.aspx?folder=5c7a05dd-7ecc-4888-9a54-4f5f63f8b501&file=CATIA_Portable_Script_Center_v2.0.zip , or you can search on eng-tips.com CATIA forum or COE.org develop and deploy forum